# How does work to Grid Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I use Material Design and try this code:

```
tiles = [
    {text: 'One', cols: 1, rows: 2, color: 'lightblue'}
  ];
```

What does it mean? That it displays 2 rows with 1 column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular has a beautiful example that answers your question: https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples

`md-grid-list` component defines the number of columns your grid will have by specifying property `cols="4"`. Then provide a list of `md-grid-tile` components inside (the example angular uses uses `ngFor`, I hope you are familiar with it).

So if you want to build matrix 5v7, then try:

```
<md-grid-list cols="7" rowHeight="100px">
  <md-grid-tile
      *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
      [colspan]="tile.cols"
      [rowspan]="tile.rows"
      [style.background]="tile.color">
    {{tile.text}}
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

and

```
@Component({
  selector: 'grid-list-dynamic-example',
  templateUrl: 'grid-list-dynamic-example.html',
})
export class GridListDynamicExample {
  tiles = [
    {text: 'One', cols: 1, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
    {text: 'Two', cols: 1, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
    {text: 'etc', cols: 1, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
    {text: 'etc', cols: 1, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
    {text: 'etc', cols: 1, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
    {text: 'etc', cols: 1, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
    {text: 'etc', cols: 1, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
    {text: '...', cols: 1, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
  ];
}
```

Comment: So, it is not good example, based on this example I asked question, because it is not clear

Comment: `cols="4" ` but I see 3

Comment: I dont understand how to build matrix 5x7

Comment: Thank you, can I set height for field?

Comment: Isn't `rowHeight="100px"` what you want?

Comment: No, I need less height for header

Comment: So then pick `rowHeight="50px"` or whatever and put `cols: 2` everywhere except for the header

Answer (score 1):

Let me break it down, first let's take a look at HTML

```
<md-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px">
  <md-grid-tile
      *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
      [colspan]="tile.cols"
      [rowspan]="tile.rows"
      [style.background]="tile.color">
    {{tile.text}}
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

cols attribute which sets the number of columns in the grid. Therefore, in this case, each row is divided into 4 columns.

Next thing is passing tiles to the grid as shown below:

```
tiles = [
{text: 'One', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
{text: 'Two', cols: 1, rows: 2, color: 'lightgreen'},
{text: 'Three', cols: 1, rows: 1, color: 'lightpink'},
{text: 'Four', cols: 2, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1'},
];
```

Here each object in titles corresponds to the item in the angular material grid.
rows attribute is used to set the height of each item, by default height of one row is 100px. So if `rows: 2` for any item, that item is going to have a height of 200px.

Reference : [Angular grid-list documentaion](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview) and 
https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples